# Image last pull date Google Container Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

On Google's Cloud Platform , in the Container Registry -
Is there a way to check when was an Image last pulled/accessed?

My use case is that I want to remove all stale images that weren't pulled for over X
amount of time.
From what I saw It can only show when an Image was created and modified.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be that the operation of Container Registry generates auditing events.  If yes, then these will be written to Cloud Logging.  Cloud Logging can then export to BigQuery and then you can "ask" BigQuery ... when was the last time someone pulled the image.

See also

https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-container-registry-statistics-from-gcs-access-logs-3be705abc413

Comment: Using last pulled is not a correct indicator of a stale image. Once an image is pulled, it is not pulled again and again (depends on the implementation). A service can run for years without re-accessing the container registry.

Comment: @Kolban Thank you for the tip i'll check it out. In any case, I'm looking for a more straight forward way to get the last pull date for an image via GCP console or gcloud cli.

Comment: @JohnHanley It is true that an Image is pulled only once in order to be run. However, in our implementation we consider an image to be stale if no services pulled it for over X amount of time.